# OpenFile not working in x86 NASM assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm

I have been using the following code for a program to open a file handle to itself and to read its contents, but I've run into a problem... Here's the code...

```
extern GetStdHandle
extern GetModuleFileNameA
extern OpenFile
extern WriteFile
extern ExitProcess

import GetStdHandle kernel32.dll
import GetModuleFileNameA kernel32.dll
import OpenFile kernel32.dll
import WriteFile kernel32.dll
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll

global ..start

segment .code USE32

;Get standard output handle for writing to the console
push dword -11
call [GetStdHandle]
mov dword [hStdOut], eax

push dword filepath ;Buffer to store filepath
push dword 0 ;Setting this to NULL retrieves file name of 
             ;the program's exe on disk
call [GetModuleFileNameA] ;ANSI format of return string (the way that
                          ;OpenFile likes it)

;Here we are checking to see if the filename was returned
;On the console it looks blank but if you dump the output of the
;program to a file using the command program.exe > program.dump the
;path shows up in a hex editor. So the path is fine...
push dword 0
push dword bytesRead
push dword 128 ;Maximum path size for OpenFile
push dword filepath
push dword [hStdOut]
call [WriteFile]

push dword 0
push dword ofstruct
push dword filepath
call [OpenFile]
mov dword [hSelfFile], eax

push dword 0
push dword bytesRead
push dword 32 ;Arbitrary number to show the beginning of
              ;hSelfFile to see if the handle is pointing to
              ;the file. It should show the magic number MZ
              ;at the beginning if we're doing this right
push dword hSelfFile
push dword [hStdOut]
call [WriteFile] 

;Here is where we should see the elusive MZ magic number in the
;output

;Yes I will use CloseHandle (even though the program automatically
;closes all open handles before exiting), but for now I need to see
;if the OpenFile actually works or not before I do such things

push 0
call [ExitProcess]

segment .data

segment .bss
hStdOut resd 1
hSelfFile resd 1
bytesRead resd 1
ofstruct resb 136
filepath resb 128
```

Sample output...

---

```
C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\Desktop\asm>test0.exe
C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\Desktop\asm\test0.exe
                                            Φ      ê☺  σF±ÿC:\DOCUME~1\Admi
C:\DOCUME~1\Admin\Desktop\asm>
```

---

What am I doing wrong with OpenFile?

Comment: Using OpenFile would be one thing you're doing wrong. The Win32 API for opening files is CreateFile.

Comment: You're also missing code to read the contents of the file.

Comment: Did you read the documentation. It starts like this: *This function has limited capabilities and is not recommended. For new application development, use the CreateFile function.*

Comment: As pointed out by Ross Ridge, you are opening the file, but never reading it. You should read (part of) the file's contents into a buffer, then pass a pointer to that buffer as the second parameter when calling `WriteFile`. Instead you are passing a pointer to the file handle: `push dword hSelfFile`

Comment: Understood. The only reason why I was doing this was because in my time playing with this code I did in fact see the elusive MZ at the top of my output, though I will use ReadFile instead. Thank you! One of you should put up the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The file needs to be read into a buffer with ReadFile before WriteFile can output the contents of the file, it cannot be read just by passing a file handle from OpenFile to WriteFile.

[Documentation...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)